# How to display custom action on the order page?

Tags: magento2

I am developing a module that will provide a personalized printing option in the mass actions of the order page, but I just wanted to show this option if the configuration is enabled in the module settings.

It is possible?

[image: Custom action]

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible :) in your module, create a file called `sales_order_grid.xml` inside `<your_module_folder>/view/adminhtml/ui_component/` folder with the following content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <action name="custom_action">
              <settings>
                  <url path="path/to/action"/>
                  <type>custom_action</type>
                  <label translate="true">Custom Action</label>
              </settings>
            </action>
        </massaction>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

Just be sure to replace the action name with a name of your choice, the `path/to/action` with the path to the controller action which will perform the actual processing of the selected orders in the grid and the label to an appropriate label of your choice.

As for limiting the existence of this option according to a setting, I would pass this responsibility to the controller action or a predispatch method which could decide whether to reroute the request to a 404/ reload page with a message that the action is unavailable OR will perform the action on the selected orders.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it will help me achieve my goal. However, I would like this option to not even appear if it was not configured to do so. I suspect that in the suggested way the option will always be visible to the user.

Comment: you are right, my suggestion will cause just that, the option will be there, but won't do the action if not enabled. i'm thinking that if you don't want to show the option at all, then i think a deeper understanding of how the options are displayed, by which block and intervene there maybe would be the solution.